# Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available on Mac/OS

Tags: python, pip, openssl, homebrew

Trying to build Python 2.7.17 and then install pip on Mac OS 10.14

Installed OpenSSL using brew

Python's build fails to build _ssl.  When I try to build pip, it fails with error "Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available

OpenSSL is correctly installed at /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python looks for ssl at /usr/local/ssl

To get it to build I did the following:
1. Set up a path to OpenSSL that didn't involve any weird characters:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/
ln -s openssl\@1.1 openssl
```

2: Ran ./configure

3: Edited Makefile replacing all "/usr/local/ssl" with "/usr/local/Cellar/openssl"

4: Run make / make test / make install

This created a Python that had _ssl, and thus pip would run

Comment: You don't have to edit the Makefile, see https://superuser.com/a/1346305/456335. You'll probably have to adjust `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` since you're building on Mac, but the rest should be pretty much the same.